# Redirecting to home page after login back arrow should not come

Tags: react-native

I am redirecting to home page after login  like

> this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');

but there back arrow came in the home page and back button coming back to login. but behavior should be no back arrow and back redirection.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't navigate to Home by navigation function. I assume you are using the latest version of react navigation which is 5. What I recommend you is create a login state in Redux at first. And do something like this

```
// I assume you get your login state from redux and saved in a variable called isLoggedIn.

if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return (
        // Auth flow
    )
} else {
    return (
        // Logged in flow
    )
}
```

Comment: I am not using redux  for now.

Comment: From my point of view, you should use a state container for that kind of authentication mechanisms.